# How to use instantiation in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clone, instantiation

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour {
    public int Player_Health = 100;
    public GameObject Player;
    public Rigidbody Bullet;
    public Transform Guun;
    public bool Player_Dead = false;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Rigidbody rocketInstance;
            rocketInstance = Instantiate(Bullet, Guun.position, Guun.rotation) as Rigidbody;
            rocketInstance.AddForce(Guun.forward * 5000);
        }

        if(Player_Health == 0)
        {
            Player_Dead = true;
        }

        if(Player_Dead == true)
        {
            Destroy(Player);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            Player_Health = Player_Health - 20;
            Debug.Log(Player_Health);
        }
    }
}
```

1.So when i instantiate by pressing space it first instantiates 1 then 2 then 4 then 8 and so on - why doesnt it just instantiate 1 each press.
I am trying to make a gun here and obviously need it to only fire one bullet at a time because at the moment it fires multiple. As i have already explained first it fires one bullet then next time i fire it doubles it and so on.

Comment: Please post your two questions as separate questions (your question is too broad because of that).

Comment: @cybermonkey they are very simple questions please at least answer one

Comment: Your second question does not make sense. Please explain that or ask it as a enw question.

Comment: That's not how this website works. It doesn't matter if they're simple questions, they need to be in different Q&As.

Comment: @Programmer could you answer the first

Comment: @cyber monkey i have made it one question- have a shot at answering?

Comment: @Programmer i have explained it- give answering it a go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.So when i instantiate by pressing space it first instantiates 1 then 2 then 4 then 8 and so on - why doesnt it just instantiate 1 each
>   press.

If the behavior is that each prefab duplicates each time the key is pressed, it simply means that the script is also attached to the prefab or multiple GameObjects. I see similar problems each time.

Please remove the script from the prefabs if it is attached to any prefab. Remove it from every GameObject in the scene then attach it to **one** GameObject only.

Select the script, go to *Assets* --> *Find References in Scene*. It will show you every GameObject that has this script attached to it. Remove it from all of them except for one.